# Add dynamically search input elements in angluar

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an API route which can accept some parameters for search (name,country,city,address,postCode...).

How can I have one input element and one select element (for user to choose between search options), and **on button click to add another input and select element** ?

For example: user select 'country' and type Spain. Next he click to add another field for search and select 'city' and type Madrid.

```
 <div>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
   <select name="">
     <option value="country">Country</option>
     <option value="city">City</option>
     <option value="address">Address</option>
   </select>
 </div>
```

Comment: Think of how Angular works : it generates the DOM from the data you have in the corresponding component. First, you need the data, that is, an array of some sort. When you click the button, add an element to the array. Immediately, the view will reflect this change. If the array has 5 elements, the view will generate 5 <div>. Use `*ngFor`

Comment: Yes, thanks. I managed to do with array of data and *ngFor.